# Why is my custom data attribute not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using jQuery

```
console.log($(this).html());
console.log($(this).data('section'));
```

yields

```
<a href="#" data-section="allothers" data-sectiontitle="Other Information" style="font-weight: 600; text-decoration: none;">Include Children?</a>
```

and

```
undefined
```

and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. The `<a>` here is inside an un-ordered list `<li>` tag, but I'm not sure why that should matter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works fine, `this` probably isn't what you think it is http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJZowK

Comment: You are both right. Thank you so much, it was the `<li>` enclosing the `<a>` as opposed to the `<a>` itself. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said it is `<li>` enclosing the `<a>`

then it should be:-

```
console.log($('li a').html());
console.log($('li a').data('section'));
```

Example:-

```js
console.log($('li a').html());
console.log($('li a').data('section'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" data-section="allothers" data-sectiontitle="Other Information" style="font-weight: 600; text-decoration: none;">Include Children?</a></li>
```

Note:- you can do `$(this).find('a').data('section');` also based on your HTML structure.

Comment: Kind of. $(this).find('a').data('section'); Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasGroenhout  glad to help you. :):)